# How to calculate the hour between two hour times in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with the following in a row as an example:
'10:00 - 16:00'.. Typically it is HOUR - HOUR2.

I am trying to get the total hours based on this. So 10:00 - 16:00 would be 6 hours. 10:00 to 16:30 will probably be 6.5 hours etc.

Is there an possible way to do this in excel with a formula?

[image]

I'm ok with it not doing the overly complex ones (Ones with several hour - hour2 in one column) but it would make it easier if it at least did the ones that are simplistic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=timevalue(RIGHT(A1,5))-timevalue(left(A1,5))
```

and then apply a `time` format to **B1** to give hours:minutes.  To get numeric hours, use:

```
=24*(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,5))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,5)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=TEXT(RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-(FIND("-",A1)+1)))-LEFT(A1,(FIND("-",A1)-2)),"hh:mm:ss")
```

**Results:**

[image]